# Message (SMS) contain text from other messages in Android

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms

Has anyone experienced this issue where the content of an SMS is not complete and some other content (from different message) is added to that at the end.

I have experienced this problem many times. And now, when I am receiving tweets as SMS via Twitter functionality, I can see this problem occurring very frequently.

Below are the H/w and S/w details, if it helps.

OS: Android 4.0.3
Made: HTC One X (AT&T)

Let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Tweets as SMS is due to your request to Twitter to send them as sms to your phone number. Make sure that option is disabled [here](https://support.twitter.com/articles/129550-how-to-change-mobile-preferences)

Comment: I do not want to turn the tweets as sms function. The problem is that one sms contains the text from other sms as well.