# SMS sent contains text from other SMS

Tags: sms, nexus-5

I sent an SMS and my contact received only part of the message I sent, to which some text I sent to another contact, a few months ago, was appended. I have proof it happened twice, but here is what it looks like:

September : I send ContactA a message: "AAA AAA"

- On my phone : "AAA AAA"
- On ContactA phone: "AAA AAA"
- On ContactB phone: [Nothing] (As you would expect)

December : I send ContactB a message: "BBB BBB"

- On my phone : "BBB BBB"
- On ContactA phone: [Nothing] (As you would expect)
- On ContactB phone: "BBB AAA AAA"

I checked with my carrier, and he told me that he saw that the text I sent ContactB was 11 characters long (it was actually way longer than that, but I ajusted the number to fit the example.)

The first time I got a proof it happened, I was using GO SMS, so I uninstalled it, and it happened again a day after using the default (Hangout) application.

I think this is a really serious problem since it violates my privacy with ContactA by revealing some conversation to ContactB.

Devise / OS Version : Nexus 5 / 5.0

Comment: It's... really an interesting case, as I never heard about this case. I actually doubt it's caused by either GO SMS or Hangouts, or even related to Nexus 5 and Lollipop. I guess it is similar to [this question, but it's unanswered too](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57951/message-sms-contain-text-from-other-messages-in-android?rq=1). It might be a problem with your carrier instead.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that question, but I asked mine still because in his questionS, he also goes toward asking stuff about subscription to Twitter. It might has something to do with my carrier, but I won't know until it rehappens. I deleted all my SMS history, so if my contact tells me it happens again, I'll tell my provider to investigate on his end.